# How to createElement on a different page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How to createElement on a different page?

I am very new to JavaScript / jQuery. I am trying to find a way to create an element on different page (please check the chart).

The functioning I am looking for:

1. Click the "ADD SECTION" button located on Page_1.html
2. The visitor will be redirected to a new page (Page_2.html) where the new div will be created

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrPIL.png)

```js
function add_section_1() {
    var section_1 = document.createElement('div');
        section_1.className = 'new_section';
        section_1.id = 'section_1';
        document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(section_1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code on Page_1 stops running when that page is unloaded to make room for Page_2. There is **nothing** Page_1 can do **directly** to change Page_2 when it's loaded.

What Page_1 *can* do is tell Page_2 that **it** should create the div. It can do that in various ways:

- Setting a value in [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) that Page_2 looks for (and then removes).
- Adding a query parameter to the query string when redirecting to Page_2 (e.g., `Page_2.html?creatediv=blah`) that Page_2 looks for on `location.search` (see [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location), [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search)).

There are probably others, but the fundamental point is: Page_1's code can't do it, but it can pass along informaton to Page_2 telling **it** to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your input Mr. Crowder, much appreciated.

However, after several hours of research and trial-and-error I still could not manage to get it working (with neither of those methods).

Could you give me more details on how those approaches would work with my actual code. Just a clarification (my intention is to make the newly created div immediately visible on Page_2, without any input from the visitor, thus "getItem" should be automatically triggered).